# Incremental Document Similarity Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bigdata, computer-science

I'm trying to calculate similarity between a large, dynamic set of text documents. For static sets, something like cosine similarity + tf-idf would work great. However, I'm looking for a scheme that will allow me to add a new document without recalculating the entire similarity set. Does any such algorithm exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be close to the solution. Simply store each instance of f(document)'s result, and combine the results.

**Map the word frequency for each document and store it:**

```
d0:
    "the" : 70,
    "quick" : 22,
    "fox" : 1

d1:
    "the" : 42,
    "lazy" : 2,
    "dog" : 13
```

**Combine the documents and evaluate on the aggregate:**

```
d0_d1:
    "the" : 112.
    "lazy" : 2,
    "dog" : 13,
    "quick" : 22,
    "fox" : 1

tf_idf(d0_d1)
```

Comment: But each time I add a document, the tf-idf values will change, rendering the previously added documents with their similarities not true anymore.

Comment: @user1000229 the takeaway aspect of my answer is to **store the mapping of each document for future use**. Once you have it an immutable mapping, key=word, value=occurrence, you've done most of the computation already. Next is to do an intersection on the keys of the documents you want to include and aggregate their values. With this new mapping, you now know word frequencies for combined documents.